# Как выбрать из таблицы строку, для которой в другой таблице есть две записи?

Tags: sql, select, join

У меня есть таблица, например,

> Horse (id, name).

Есть таблица

> Schedule (id, hourse_id, id_sedlo).

1. Первая таблица содержит идентификаторы лошади;
2. Вторая таблица содержит график ношения лошадьми сёдел (ед.ч. седло)

Мне надо выбрать лошадь, которая носила седло номер 10 и 15. То есть, два разных седла.
С помощью каких средств синтаксиса языка SQL это реализовывается? Нужны ли подзапросы?

Comment: Отбор, группировка и подсчёт количества уникальных значений. Подзапросы не нужны.

Comment: @Akina , хорошо, а если мне надо вывести всех лошадей, которые носили эти сёдла (10 и 15)? да и что вы имели ввиду - не до конца понял. Как мне написать в запросе, что мне надо найти лошадь, у которой есть строка в таблице Schedule (1, 2, 10) и (2, 2, 15)?? Я же не могу написать: WHERE  Schedule.id_sedlo = 10 AND Schedule.id_sedlo = 15.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT H.name
FROM Horse AS H
JOIN Schedule AS S ON H.id = S.hourse_id
WHERE id_sedlo IN (10, 15)
GROUP BY H.name
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: Лучше всё-таки `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT id_sedlo) = 2`. Нет никакой гарантии, что `(hourse_id, id_sedlo)`  объявлено уникальным.

Comment: тут смотреть на особенность БД, лишняя конструкция - это просадка производительности, но если таблица небольшая, то можно для подстраховки добавить. Но надо понимать, что если в таблице не должно быть дубликатов, а они есть, то нужно разбираться с первопричинами, а не бороться с последствиями.

Comment: Исходя из смысла - таблица тупо хранит сведения, когда на какую лошадь какое седло навьючивали. И то, что для какой-то лошади сегодня седло то же, что и позавчера, но не то, что вчера - вполне обычное дело, никак не вылезающее за рамки логики. Так что именно в этом случае надежда на уникальность указанной пары - более чем призрачна. А первопричина соответственно особенность предметной области, а никак не косяк.